# How are chain maps of refinement defined?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

This is [definition 1.4.5, p6](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~bruno.klingler/cours/courspervers.pdf). [image]

What confuses me is that what does it mean for the **orientations of $\sigma$ and $\sigma'$ to be compatible?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An orientation of an $n$-simplex $\sigma \in \cal N$ is a choice of one of two equivalences classes of orderings of its vertex set, where two orderings are equivalent if the re-ordering map is an even permutation.

For example, letting $\Delta^n$ denote the "standard" rectilinear $n$-simplex in $\mathbb R^n$, with vertex set $0,p_1,...,p_n$ where $p_i$ is all zeroes except for a $1$ in the $i$th coordinate, the *positive* orientation is the equivalence class of the ordering $0,p_1,...,p_n$.

Given orientation on the simplex $\sigma$ in this question, there is a simplicial homeomorphism
$$f : \sigma \mapsto \Delta^n
$$
that takes the given orientation on $\sigma$ to the positive orientation on $\Delta^n$, and $f$ is well-defined up to composition with an orientation preserving simplicial isomorphism $\Delta^n \mapsto \Delta^n$.

The refinement $\cal N'$ restricts to a triangulation of $\sigma$ itself, which is mapped via $f$ to a triangulation of $\Delta^n$. For each $\sigma' \in \cal N'$ such that $\sigma' \subset \sigma$, its image $f(\sigma') \subset \Delta^n$ is a rectilinear $n$-simplex in $\mathbb R^n$, and the orientation on $\sigma'$ is taken by $f$ to an orientation on $f(\sigma')$.

So now suppose that $\sigma'$ is an $n$-simplex. Let $g : f(\sigma') \to f(\sigma)$ be a simplicial isomorphism that takes a positively oriented list of the vertices of $f(\sigma')$ to a positively oriented list of vertices of $f(\sigma)$. This map $g$ extends to an affine homeomorphism of $\mathbb R^n$, i.e. it has the form $g(p) = Mp+q$ for some invertible $n \times n$ matrix $M$. One can ask: Does $M$ have positive determinant or negative determinant? If $M$ has positive determinant then we say that $\sigma,\sigma'$ have compatible orientation, otherwise they have incompatible orientation.